# How do I roll a date forward to a specified day in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-arithmetic

I'm working on a form that needs to automatically calculate the day the form is being submitted in the format ('MMDDYYYY'), and then on the click of one of two links a link, calculate the closest first day of the coming month, and the closest 15th day of the coming month.

I already created a script that pulls in the date and outputs it to a variable in the format I need, but I need help in calculating the roll forward.

Here's an example of the logic I'm thinking I need:

If the current date is 04092013, on a the button press labeled "Coming 1st of Month" a variable value of 05012013 would be calculated.

If the current date is 04092013, on a button press labeled "Coming 15th of Month" a variable value of 04152013 would be calculated.

If the current date is 04162013 or any date up to the end of the current month, on a button press labeled "Coming 15th of Month" a variable value of 05152013 would be calculated.

Comment: Have a look at the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and specifically [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) and [`setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) methods..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Date object, it should provide what you need:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

For example something like this for your first 2 buttons:

```
$(function() {
    var date = new Date(2013, 10, 24);

    $("#date").html(date.toString());
    $("#date1").html((new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 1)).toString());
    $("#date2").html((new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 15)).toString());
});
```

(Though I'm sure there are easier ways to do this if you look through the Date documenation)

Comment: Thanks. That's a helpful link. I'll take a look and see if I can glean some knowledge from there.

Comment: This worked. I simply applied the script I had already written to reformat the output of the date object, and I had my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. If you want it back as a string, you'll have to format it at the end as desired (work with *UTC* ).

If you put in a date that has the same day number as you're asking of it, it returns the same day, not moving forwards a month.

```
var date_string = '04092013';
                // MMDDYYYY

function nextNthOfMonth(date_string, n) {
    var date;
    // n to Int, default 1
    n = (+n || 1);
    // date_string to ISO 8601
    date_string = // "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
          date_string.slice(4)
        + '-' + date_string.slice(0, 2)
        + '-' + date_string.slice(2, 4)
        + 'T00:00:00Z';
    // construct date object
    date = new Date(date_string);
    // fix to desired date
    if (n < date.getUTCDate()) { // adjust for month if req.
        date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth() + 1);
    }
    date.setUTCDate(n);
    return date; // or format as desired
}

nextNthOfMonth(date_string, 1);
// Wed May 01 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
nextNthOfMonth(date_string, 15);
// Mon Apr 15 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getDate() {
    var s = document.getElementById('date').value;
    if(s){
        return new Date(s.substring(4), parseInt(s.substring(2, 4), 10) - 1, s.substring(0, 2))
    }
}

function comingDate(date, day){
    date = new Date(date);
    var cday = date.getDate();
    date.setDate(day);
    if(cday >= day){
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)
    }
    return date
}

function f15(){
    var d = getDate();
    var next = comingDate(d, 15);
    console.log(next)
}

function f1(){
    var d = getDate();
    var next = comingDate(d, 1);
    console.log(next)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/avmca/)

Comment: Thanks Arun. I gave this a try in jFiddle, and it doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the format of your date, split the input into parts:

```
var dateStr = '04092013'
var month = dateStr.substr(0,2);
var day = dateStr.substr(2,2);
var year = dateStr.substr(4,4);
```

The construct a new date base on the rule you want to set:

```
var newDate;
switch(rule)
{
  case 'rule1':
  newDate = new Date(year, month, 1);//first month is 0
  break;
  case 'rule2':
  newDate = new Date(year, month, 15);//first month is 0
  break;
}
```

- remember to check if the day is greater that 15.